# PayPal Cart upload button secure?

Tags: security, upload, paypal, shopping-cart

If I create a button using the PayPal button manager, is it automatically secure just because it's hosted? Even if I use to upload a cart?

This is how I'm using it on the website:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JRECLRTYAJDKY">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a hosted button, it would be secure and prevent someone from modifying the code and setting the amount to a lower amount and etc.  You wouldn't be able to create a cart upload button.  You would only be able to create one of the following types of buttons.

BUYNOW - Buy Now button

CART - Add to Cart button

GIFTCERTIFICATE - Gift Certificate button

SUBSCRIBE - Subscribe button

DONATE - Donate button

UNSUBSCRIBE - Unsubscribe button

VIEWCART - View Cart button

PAYMENTPLAN - Installment Plan button; since version 63.0

AUTOBILLING - Automatic Billing button; since version 63.0

PAYMENT - Pay Now button; since version 65.1